# Session times out regardless of user activity

Tags: php, session

A data entry form on one of my sites is such that users may stay on it for quite long periods inputting records. However, the page times out after approx 25 minutes, even if users have been continually inputting records (each one takes about 3-5 minutes). It always times out immediately after a user has saved a record and the page is refreshing. My code detects that session variables are unset and sends the user back to the login form.

The data entry page begins with session_start(), which I thought reset the session timeout timer. I've tried amending session.gc_maxlifetime to a higher value (using ini_set) but this seems to have no effect.

How do I force the session to reset its timer so that users can stay on the data input page indefinitely? (Timeout after a period in which a user doesn't
input data is already dealt with by a JS script.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can refresh something after a given amount of time in JavaScript: The setInterval() function.

```
setInterval(function(){  <?php /*Here goes the code you want to refresh*/ ?> }, /*Time in miliseconds, in this example 3 secs:*/ 3000);
```